# 'Undefined variable “matlab” or class “matlab.addons.installedAddons”' when running launch.m in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, webots

I want to control a robot using MATLAB in Webots 2019a. When I start the simulation using launch.m, it always fails. The information of the error is:  **Undefined variable "matlab" or class "matlab.addons.installedAddons"**  How can I solve this problem? Is it because I'm using the wrong MATLAB version? My MATLAB version is 2016b.

Comment: According to the documentation, the command was introduced in 2017b, which means you are trying to run code which is incompatible to MATLAB 2016b.

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.addons.installedaddons.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are on Windows, right?
In that case, you probably need to install the 'MATLAB MinGW-w64 C/C++ Compiler' addon as explained here: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-matlab#matlab-installation